# C++ Why is the output of this code 3? (structs)

Tags: c++, struct, integer

Can someone help me understand step-by-step why the following C++ code outputs a 3?

```cpp
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

struct sct
{
    int t[2];
};

struct str
{
    sct t[2];
};

int main() {
    str t[2] = { {0,2,4,6}, {1,3,5,7} };
    std::cout << t[1].t[0].t[1];
}
```

Comment: What do you think it should output?

Comment: first t[1] is {1,3,5,7}, second t[0] is {1,3}, third t[1] is 3.

Comment: This appears to be some [assessment question](https://www.ccna7.com/cpa-programming-essentials-in-c/cpa-chapter-2-assessment-answers-100/)?  Do you understand any of this code?  Where are you lost?

Comment: I am confused on the t[0] part. Does the sct structure put the first two integers {1,3} from the array {1,3,5,7} selected by the first t[1] into it's array?

Comment: I suggest you rename the members of the structs, to make it easier to read.

Comment: @cal223 it may help you to think of `str t[2] = { {0,2,4,6}, {1,3,5,7} };` as `str t[2] = { { {0,2}, {4,6} }, { {1,3}, {5,7} } };` instead, because that is basically what it is really doing.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now after renaming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`t[1]` is `{1,3,5,7}`.

`str` is represented in memory as four integers back-to-back, organized into 2 `sct` structures. In this case, the first one has the values 1 and 3, while the second contains 5 and 7.

Thus, `t[1].t[0]` is `{1,3}`, so `t[1].t[0].t[1]` is 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
str t[2] = { {0,2,4,6}, {1,3,5,7} };
```

This means we are an array of two `str` values `{0,2,4,6}` at 0 index and `{1,3,5,7}` at index 1.

```
cout<<t[0]  //gives 0,2,4,6
cout<<t[1]  //gives 1,3,5,7
```

Now, when in question `cout << t[1].t[0].t[1];` we see what is in `t[1]` i.e `(1,3,5,7)`, and with that we go inside the `str` block to assign `t[1]` to a variable of type `stc`. Inside it there, we find another variable `t[2]` of type `stc`. Here we divide our previous value as `t[1].t[0]=1,3` and `t[1].t[1]=5,7`.
Now, when in question `cout << t[1].t[0].t[1];` we see what is in `t[1].t[0]=1,3`, and with that we go inside the `stc` block to assign `t[1].t[0]` to a variable of type `int`. Inside it there, we find another variable `t[2]` of type `int`. Here we divide our previous value as `t[1].t[0].t[0]=1` and `t[1].t[0].t[1]=3`.
Now, when in question `cout << t[1].t[0].t[1];` we see what is in `t[1].t[0].t[1]=3`, and then it gets printed due to `cout`!!!!!